# Suppose we have an array having 0 to n-1 distinct integers example {2,1,4,3,5,0} find output

Tags: arrays, data-structures, language-agnostic, big-o

Suppose we have an array having 0 to n-1 distinct integers

example

`{2,1,4,3,5,0}`

our goal is to modify this array such that `a[0]` becomes `a[a[0]]` means `a[0]` has value 2 here so `a[0]` = `a[2]` and so on.

Having the following output :

`{4,1,5,3,0,2}`.

Three things are to be noted here that:

1. positions have range 0 to n-1 and values have range 0 to n-1 too (obviously).
2. no extra array or link list or any data structure should be taken.
3. should have time complexity O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the idea:

You can store the original and desired numbers in the same array position by keeping the original one and pushing the new one as a base n number.

That way, to extract the original number we just need to compute the modulo n operation:

`original = array[index] % array.length`

And we can get the target value dividing by the array length

`target = array[index] / array.length`

That way we won't require additional memory and we will be able to do it in two passes `O(2n) complexity`.

The algorithm is pretty straightforward (implemented in python):

```py
def self_permute(arr):
    length = len(arr)
    for i in range(length):
        if arr[i] < i:
            arr[i] += (arr[arr[i]] % length) * length
        else:
            arr[i] += arr[arr[i]] * length

    for i in range(length):
        arr[i] /= length

    return arr

a = [2,1,4,3,5,0]
print self_permute(a)
```

Comment: Awsome thinking man!!!!! 2 things time complexity will be 3n as n time for calculation of Length too and i dont think if else is required. arr[i] += (arr[arr[i]] % length) * length will work normally if the value is not processed too. thanks anyway